# Sleep oder wait in For-Loop

Tags: java, android, wait, flashlight, postdelayed

I'm trying to turn the LED on and of for a particular lenght (out_tic), based on a given Text in Morse-Code(Text).
I tried to solve this with a "postDelay" and also with sleep() or wait() , but the flash has allways the same lenght or the app crashes..
I think it's because the Flash is told to start when it hasn't closed yet.

```
cam = Camera.open();
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    for(int i=0;i<Text.length();i++){

        if(Text.charAt(i)=='.' ||Text.charAt(i)=='·'){
            ledon();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                 public void run() {
                     ledoff();
                     } 
            }, out_tic);


        }
        else if(Text.charAt(i)=='-'){
            ledon();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                 public void run() {
                     ledoff();
                     } 
            }, 3*out_tic);
        }
        else if(Text.charAt(i)=='/'){
            if(Text.charAt(i-1)=='/'){

            }
        }

    }
```

The ledon() and ledoff() Methodes just set Parameters and start/stop the Preview.

Thanks for your help!

**New code that works for me:**

*(Due to JRaymond)*

```
final String Text = "./-..-/.-/--/.--./.-.././/";
final int out_tic = 200;

new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<Text.length();i++){

        if(Text.charAt(i)=='.' ||Text.charAt(i)=='·'){
        flash(out_tic);
        flashpause(out_tic);
        continue;
        }
        else if(Text.charAt(i)=='-'){
        flash(3*out_tic);
        flashpause(out_tic);
        continue;
        }
        else if(Text.charAt(i)=='/'){
            flashpause(2*out_tic);
            if(Text.charAt(i-1)=='/'){
                flashpause(4*out_tic);
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }).start();
}

        private Handler handler = new Handler();
private void flash(final int sleeptime) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ledon();
        }
    });
    try {
        Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
    }
    handler.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            ledoff();
        }
    });
}

private void flashpause(final int sleeptime)    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
            }
}

private Camera cam;
private void ledon() {
    cam = Camera.open();     
    Parameters params = cam.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    cam.setParameters(params);
    cam.startPreview();
}
private void ledoff() {
    cam.stopPreview();
    cam.release();
}
```

Comment: I assume You're using FLASH_MODE_TORCH? Note that not all devices support this mode

Comment: @JRaymond Yes I'm using FLASH_MODE_TORCH. Actually, the flashlight works well, but not the lenght of each flashs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've pieced out your puzzle- all of your runnables are getting posted so that they occur at pretty much the same time.  `postDelayed` schedules the `Runnable` for a time from now, not from the time that the last `Runnable` was scheduled.  I think your best solution would be something like this, which offloads the LED control to another thread:

```
cam = Camera.open();
Handler handler = new Handler();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    for(int i=0;i<Text.length();i++){
      if(Text.charAt(i)=='.' ||Text.charAt(i)=='·') {
        flash(out_tic);
        continue;
      }
      else if(Text.charAt(i)=='-'){
        flash(3 * out_tic)
        continue;
      }
      // I don't quite understand what this does, but the same principles apply
      else if(Text.charAt(i)=='/'){
        //Warte 2*out_tic lang (1mal wurde schon gewartet)
        if(Text.charAt(i-1)=='/'){

        }
      }
    }
  }
  private void flash(int tic) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        ledon();
      }
    });
    try {
          Thread.sleep(out_tic);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        ledoff();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Note that the above is pretty messy, you might want to move things around and clean it up a little - but the idea is that you let a different thread from the UI do the sleeping and then post back to the handler when the Camera parameters need to be changed.

Comment: @ JRaymond
Thank you!! I changed it a bit and now it works fine :D i'ts just the wait Operation that isnt accurate at all, but with bigger terms it fits perfectly :)
sourc code can be found at the top ;)

Comment: @Alrick yeah the `Thread.sleep()` method isn't super precise - but for most purposes it works well enough - glad I could help!